# One-To-Many Batch Cascade delete

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have 2 Entity tables and one relation table for both the entities. Relationship defined like following:

**Entity 1:**

```
@JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Set<Entity1Entity2Relation> relations;
```

**Entity 2**

```
@JsonIgnore
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "id", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Set<Entity1Entity2Relation> relations;
```

**Relation table:**

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "propertyId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Entity1 obj1;

@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
@JoinColumn(name = "structureId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
private Entity2 obj2;
```

If one of the entity1 is deleted I want it's corresponding relation entries to be deleted as well and similar with Entity 2.

What I am missing here?

Answer (score 0):

what issues/errors are you having with this mapping?

I see some mappings that need to change. You should remove `@JoinColumn` annotation on the `@OneToMany` mapping. You already have a specified `@JoinColumn` on the many-to-one side, so there's no need to specify it on the one-to-many side. Usually, you place the `@JoinColumn` on the owning side of the relationship. In a one-to-many/many-to-one bi-directional relationship, you place the `@JoinColumn` on the field mapped with `@ManyToOne`.

Also, to specify the inverse side of the bi-directional relationship, your `@OneToMany` annotation should have a `mappedBy` attribute.

Applying my suggestions, would result in the ff. code:

```
@Entity
public class Entity1 {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy="obj1")
    private Set<Entity1Entity2Relation> relations;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Entity2 {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE}, mappedBy="obj2")
    private Set<Entity1Entity2Relation> relations;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Entity1Entity2Relation {
    ...
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "propertyId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Entity1 obj1;

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade={CascadeType.REMOVE})
    @JoinColumn(name = "structureId", updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private Entity2 obj2;
    ...
}
```

Comment: It did not work. Entity1Entity2Relation entries are not going away.

Comment: Please show your code on how to do the deletion (showing all the entities involved). Perhaps, some DAO code.